# Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Node'. Typescript error

Tags: javascript, typescript, selection

I am working on a project and I'm getting this typescript error saying `Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Node'.`

[image: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Node'.]

I have destructured `anchorNode` from the selection Object in javascript

```js
const selection = window.getSelection()
const {anchorNode} = selection;
```

Even though I'm able to read the length property of the `anchorNode` typescript is saying that it does not exist on the type Node.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If `length` is not defined in type "Node" then you can do something like this `(anchorNode as any).length;`. This tells typescript to treat anchorNode as any type

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it a bug in typescript?

Comment: Not a bug, `length` is not a property of [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node).

Comment: `selection.anchorNode` can be any `Node`, not necessarely a `Text` so typescript can't know in advance if it has a length property

Comment: ...but if you casted that variable as Text, typescript was not going to complain when trying to access to its length property (if not at runtime in case the selection wasn't a Text node)

Answer (score 2):

The anchor generally [returns a single `Node` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/anchorNode#value), therefore, if you take a look at the [`Node` properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node#instance_properties), you can see that there is no `length` property.

Sure, the javascript can try to do some magic under the hood, like type casting and give you the length. But typescript is just saying that the class doesn't have the this `length` property.

I couldn't figure out what length you want out of the `anchorNode`, but I suppose it is the length of his children, which you can get using:

```
const length = anchorNode.childNodes.length;
```

This is a code to get the DOM elements under `anchorNode`, and since the `childNodes` returns a `NodeList`, we can get the [property `length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/length) from it.

---

Now, if you want the text length, then just extract the text from the node:

```
const length = anchorNode.textContent.length;
```

Just keep in mind that the extracted text includes the [text from the children as well.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Comment: [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/length) has it's own `length` property.

Comment: You're right. I didn't knew that, I'll edit it right now. Thanks